# python pandas tax calculation: calculate the tax according to the given senario and add it to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
country  product quantity   price              final_price
India     laptop  50        30000             
USA       laptop  50        30000
China     laptop  100       30000
India     mobile  50        10000
USA       mobile  50        10000
China     mobile  100       10000

country_tax = {"india":0%,"usa":3%,"china":4%}
product_tax = {"laptop":2%,"mobile":3%}
```

final price is the new column where the calculated tax should be appended
can anyone suggest me a good way to do this by using lambda

Thanks

Comment: you can use `map`

Comment: @Dinesh do you want to add the tax or subtract the tax? how does quantity factor in?

Comment: I want to add tax and please ignore the quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
country_tax = {'India': 0, 'USA': 3, 'China': 4}
product_tax = {'laptop': 2, 'mobile': 3}

df['final_price'] = df['price'] + (df['country'].map(country_tax) * df['price'] 
                    + df['product'].map(product_tax) * df['price']) / 100
print(df)

# Output
  country product  quantity  price  final_price
0   India  laptop        50  30000      30600.0
1     USA  laptop        50  30000      31500.0
2   China  laptop       100  30000      31800.0
3   India  mobile        50  10000      10300.0
4     USA  mobile        50  10000      10600.0
5   China  mobile       100  10000      10700.0
```

**Update**

> Is there any chance of using lambda function for this

Less efficient but lambda:

```
get_final_price = lambda x: x['price'] + (x['price'] * country_tax[x['country']] 
                            + x['price'] * product_tax[x['product']]) / 100

df['final_price'] = df.apply(get_final_price, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
  country product  quantity  price  final_price
0   India  laptop        50  30000      30600.0
1     USA  laptop        50  30000      31500.0
2   China  laptop       100  30000      31800.0
3   India  mobile        50  10000      10300.0
4     USA  mobile        50  10000      10600.0
5   China  mobile       100  10000      10700.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```
country_tax = {"India":0,"USA":3,"China":4}
product_tax = {"laptop":2,"mobile":3}

df['final_price'] = (1 + (df['country'].map(country_tax) + df['product'].map(product_tax)) / 100) * df['price']
```

The same result can be obtained using a lambda function:

```
df['final_price'] = (1 + (df['country'].apply(lambda x: country_tax[x]) + df['product'].apply(lambda x: product_tax[x])) / 100) * df['price']
```

Output:

```
  country product  quantity  price  final_price
0   India  laptop        50  30000      30600.0
1     USA  laptop        50  30000      31500.0
2   China  laptop       100  30000      31800.0
3   India  mobile        50  10000      10300.0
4     USA  mobile        50  10000      10600.0
5   China  mobile       100  10000      10700.0
```